# SELECT When child record doesn't exist

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have two tables `parent` and `children`.  The `parent.mopid` and `children.mopid` is the connection between the two tables.  How would I write a `SELECT` that would end result show me just the parent records where there are no children records?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `NOT IN` function:

```
SELECT * from parent
where parent.mopid NOT IN (SELECT mopid from children)
```

This will return all rows from the parent table that do not have a corresponding mopid in the childrens table.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a lot of rows, a `LEFT JOIN` is often quicker than a `NOT IN`. But not always - it depends on the data so please try this answer and the one from @aktrazer and see which works best for you.

```
SELECT parent.*
FROM parent
LEFT JOIN children ON parent.mopid = children.mopid
WHERE children.mopid IS NULL
```

If there isn't a `children` row for the `mopid`, `parent.mopid` will have a value but `child.mopid` will be null.

Comment: Not necessarily as explained in this article, depends on the data and other factors: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/

Comment: You're right @aktrazer, and sorry - I shouldn't make a sweeping statement like that. I'll alter my answer to make it less strident, and I'll up-vote your answer because (a) it works and (b) the OP should try both solutions and determine which is faster based on their data.

Comment: Not a problem, we're all here to learn and help out.  Your answer was 100% right, OP should just try both and see which one works better for him.

Comment: You're too kind @aktrazer - as you continue with SO you'll see soon enough that some folks will downvote without explanation rather than state their case candidly. I much prefer your approach :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * from parent p where NOT EXISTS 
( select mopid from children c where p.mopid = c.mopid)
```

This should take care of the nulls as well

This link will explain you the difference between NOT IN and NOT EXISTS

[NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173041/not-in-vs-not-exists)

Comment: Well played.  Learn something new every day.